# replace non NA values of numpy array with value calculated by formula

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Y is a np array containing NA values and numeric values. I want to replace all non-NA values with a value Y_new calculated by the formula below:

```
Y_min = np.nanmin(Y)
Y_max = np.nanmax(Y)

Y_new = (np.log(Y)-np.log(Y_min))/(np.log(Y_max)-np.log(Y_min))
```

How to do so, while leaving the NA values there and only changing the non-NA values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to just put them back in by creating a mask using `np.isnan`.

```
Y_new = (np.log(Y) - np.log(Y_min)) / (np.log(Y_max) - np.log(Y_min))
Y_new[np.isnan(Y)] = np.nan
```